# How to do a GroupBy correctly in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, group-by

I'm trying to make a query that groups records and returns the index of one of the fields, something like this, in SQL:

| unit | contract | day | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-01 | 08:00 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-01 | 12:00 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-01 | 16:37 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-02 | 07:59 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-02 | 12:00 |
| 0001 | 6 | 2023-03-02 | 08:02 |
| 0001 | 6 | 2023-03-02 | 11:58 |

```
SELECT 
    unit,
    contract,
    day,
    hour
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unit, contract, day ORDER BY unit, contract, hour) AS NUMBER
FROM MyTable
```

And I would like a return like this:

| unit | contract | day | hour | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-01 | 08:00 | 1 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-01 | 12:00 | 2 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-01 | 16:37 | 3 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-02 | 07:59 | 1 |
| 0001 | 1 | 2023-03-02 | 12:00 | 2 |
| 0001 | 6 | 2023-03-02 | 08:02 | 1 |
| 0001 | 6 | 2023-03-02 | 11:58 | 2 |

In short, the column 'number' would tell me the order of entries in that unit, in that contract and on that day.

So I tried to make this query in LINQ using group by and select many:

```
var query = MyTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.Unit,
        x.Contract,
        x.Day
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Select((y, i) => new
    {
        Unit = z.Unit,
        Contract = z.Contract,
        Day = z.Day,
        Hour = z.Hour
        Number = i + 1,
    }))
    .ToList();
```

I confess that some concepts of using group by and select many in LINQ are still not clear to me, so I was certainly wrong in some aspects, but specifically in this query above, the result is not being returned the way I would like. In the fictitious data that I put in the first table to illustrate, the first case of group by (unit 0001, contract 1 and day 2023-03-01) has 3 records, in my query in LINQ it is returning the first result (hour 08:00) thousands of times, as well as the other results later, that is, I can't get only the 3 data I would like.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me and possibly help me understand this question better.

Comment: don't do `AsEnumerable` - with that thats all done in memory!

Comment: when I remove it, the query returns the following: `The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.` How should I proceed in this case?

Comment: you can try the below code without AsEnumberable 
var query = MyTable
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Unit, x.Contract, x.Day })
    .ToList() // Retrieve records from the database and group them in memory
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => new {
        g.Key.Unit,
        g.Key.Contract,
        g.Key.Day,
        x.Hour,
        Number = i + 1
    }))
    .ToList();